# How to setup a debuggable project, that statically links libraries?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, makefile, openocd

I am working under `Eclipse` with `gcc` for `bare metal ARM`. The version control is `SVN` and the make system is `make`.

The project is quite large, and it would be beneficial to extract some areas into external libraries. The libraries are to be compiled, collected within an `.a` file, and the main project will statically link against them.

I managed to do this. The library has it's own `makefile`, which the project `makefile` calls. The linking is ok. However, I have trouble when trying to setup debugging! A "Hard fault" occurs within the CPU, and the debugger reports:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.7.0 (2013-05-05-10:44)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
WARNING!
This file was not tested with real interface, but is assumed to work as this
interface uses the same layout as configs that were verified. Please report your
experience with this file to openocd-devel mailing list, so it could be marked
as working or fixed.
Info : only one transport option; autoselect 'jtag'
adapter speed: 500 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
jtag_ntrst_delay: 100
cortex_m3 reset_config sysresetreq
adapter speed: 3000 kHz
Info : clock speed 3000 kHz
Info : JTAG tap: sam4.cpu tap/device found: 0x4ba00477 (mfg: 0x23b, part: 0xba00, ver: 0x4)
Info : sam4.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : JTAG tap: sam4.cpu tap/device found: 0x4ba00477 (mfg: 0x23b, part: 0xba00, ver: 0x4)
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x004000d0 msp: 0x2001fffc
force hard breakpoints
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection from 3333
Warn : acknowledgment received, but no packet pending
Error: JTAG-DP STICKY ERROR
Error: MEM_AP_CSW 0x23000052, MEM_AP_TAR 0xfffffffc
Error: JTAG-DP STICKY ERROR
Error: MEM_AP_CSW 0x23000052, MEM_AP_TAR 0xfffffffc
Warn : Block read error address 0xfffffff8
Error: JTAG-DP STICKY ERROR
Error: MEM_AP_CSW 0x23000052, MEM_AP_TAR 0xfffffffc
Error: JTAG-DP STICKY ERROR
Error: MEM_AP_CSW 0x23000052, MEM_AP_TAR 0xfffffffc
Warn : Block read error address 0xfffffff8
```

Comment: You only have this problem when linking to the libraries?  Does a simple program that doesn't depend on a library debug OK?

Comment: @MichaelBurr, not sure, the project is quite complex, with 500 lines makefile, custom linker script, hardware dependencies. The library is being extracted from it. Maybe I am not setting up the linker script correct.

Comment: You should create a simple project - for example, a loop that toggles an LED every second or so - just to validate that the JTAG is set up and working correctly.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, the project debugs fine. But when I extract a library, build it separately and statically link to it, calling a function from the library causes a "Hard fault".

Comment: when you link in the library, are you able to get the debugger to work before the function is called? What I mean is, can you set a breakpoint before the call, then disassemble and/or step through the call one instruction at a time? Also, take a look at the map file to see if the function is being located somewhere that it shouldn't be.